# How do I make the unused space inside a div act like a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website, but this type of page I have created has a bit of a problem. If you click on the background, you're supposed to go back to another page, but I've got two divs inside a parent div, that are supposed to be blocking this action. This is not the problem.

[image: This is an screenshot of the page with some visual explaination]

I want to make the unused space inside the parent div to act exactly like the background. On some other pages, it's the other column that has space left underneath.

I've already tried to make a div use the max width and height in one of the columns, but that makes it so the actual content is pushed off of the page.
I've already tried to make the parent div into a button, like the background, but this action made the whole page a giant button.

Is there a solution for this kind of thing?

Comment: Nice effort of explanation, but it's incomplete, we know absolutely nothing about the css methodology that you have undertaken. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example then come back here and show our this with minimal code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `point-events: none` in your styling. This allows you to click directly through an item, and have your click register on the item directly behind it. You will need to set `pointer-events: auto` for any child elements that shouldn't be clicked through.

You can read more about this here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @user15055153 Glad it helped! Make sure to click the button beside the answer to mark this as the correct answer, and good luck on your project!